# problem in printing the json i see using firebug

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

hi i see my json returned from google with a status code 200 and response but i am not able to use the json data returned in the callback i provided. below is the code.

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=ajax& 
destination=toronto&region=ca&avoid=tolls&sensor=false&callback=?",function(json)

        {

            alert("Some Success"+json);

        });


]
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` toolbar button to format source code. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `callback` with `jsoncallback` in your URL

**UPDATE:** In response to your comment, try replacing `xml` in the URL with `json` as well. The URL you're using seems to be returning XML.

Comment: still not able to alert the response came back. Do i have decode json before sending it to alert ?